# How do I limit Rails 3 view to items in a specific relationship category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a classified listing style website and I'm pretty new to Rails... Hence this question.

I have setup the listing data with scaffolds and have an MVC for my Posts, Categories, and Subcategories. I have the relationships working with `belongs_to` & `has_many`... I've been able to find a way to list the subcategories that belong to each respective category with this code: `<% if subcategory.category.id == category.id %>` I'm not sure if this is the most efficient method for the views (i.e. with server & database requirements and all), but my real question is how to list only the posts that belong to a certain category & subcategory. Right now, the main view (reminiscent of the craigslist homepage) lists each category & subcategory and each links to the Subcategories `index` view. I have been unable to find a way to limit the view to just the category or subcategory that someone clicks to take them here.

How would I go about doing that?

Also, I want to setup the custom URL's based on the category/subcategory that a user clicks (e.g. domain.com/subcategory)... It seems best to mention that as it could come into play now with how to design this current functionality.

Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails models have many powerful methods for various kinds of searches.

For example, if you have added

```
has_many :subcategories
```

to your `Category` model, your list of subcategories of a certain category should be available via:

```
category.subcategories
```

Your best bet is to have a good read of the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), particularly [this one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and [this one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback... I'll checkout the links and see if that solves my problem. I have this part (the relationships & viewing all the data) working, but my problem is that I have created several categories, and I want to show only the posts that belong to one specific category I created... For example, I want to see all the posts where the 'category_id' is 12.

Comment: I checked out the links... Looks like I have my answer for accessing the posts based on 'subcategory_id', Thank YOU! I created an '@requested_category' in my application_controller, but my problem now it setting that variable (i.e. with the 'subcategory_id' which the user clicked on in the category view) to be able to call it in the subsequent view. Any ideas/guidance?

Comment: consider creating another question for that.

Comment: That's what I was asking in this question... Or trying to at least

Comment: I don't have enough information to help you.  You will need to show in more detail what you are trying, and what you want to acheive.

Comment: Turns out it I has 'subcategories' misspelled in the 'has_many' relationship... Minor details!